# Can a mysql user be restricted to a max number of rows per select query?

Tags: mysql, database, permissions

I've found that it's possible to grant user access to only specific tables in a DB. The next part of the puzzle is restricting the scope of select queries.

Should my frontend server ever be compromised by someone able to script, they may attempt to use mysql credentials from the server to dump the database.

If everything is limited to only select, update, and insert queries via mysql privileges, the supposed malicious user could still select * on the tables the mysql user has access to. Perhaps I'm overly paranoid, but I'm wondering if anything can be done to restrict that too.

The assumption here is that if the server is compromised, the mysql user can be used via a script on the server to get a copy of everything in the DB. I'm trying to find the options to protect my (and my users' data).

By design, the frontend application that will use this mysql user will never need to return more than 20 rows (mostly due to hardcoded . I'm therefore happy to restrict the mysql user from ever getting more than 20 rows from a select query.

Can this be done using mysql privileges for that mysql user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create `view` as `select ... limit 20`, remove select privilege from the table and grant it only for the view instead.

Comment: This is a very good idea. That way full access to the table isn't there, only limited chunks, regardless of the query coming from the frontend. Thanks!